# Showing or hiding elements in table with css, javascript scrolls the datatable to top everytime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I have a large table which I rendered with [datatables](https://datatables.net/). It is large so I used scroll x and y . and I have added buttons to show/hide child rows with the help of CSS / javascript like below.

```
 // for default : shown
        $("input:checkbox.clicktohide:not(:checked)").each(function() {
         var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
         $(column).hide();
        });

     $("input:checkbox.clicktohide").click(function(){
         var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
         $(column).toggle();
        }); 

        // for default : hidden
        $("input:checkbox.clicktoshow:not()").each(function() {
         var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
         $(column).hide();
        });

        $("input:checkbox.clicktoshow").click(function(){
            var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
            $(column).toggle();
        });
```

It works in showing or hiding rows. But the problem occurs each time when I click to show/hide button, table automatically scrolls to the top. I need the table position to be stable during show/hide. 
Thanks

UPDATE : I have tried to use datatables function on a button click but it doesn't work. See below

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready( function () {
        var table = $('#shipmentshortage').DataTable({
            paging:   false,
            "ordering": false,
            scrollY:        '75vh',
            scrollX:        true,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            searching: false,
            info: false,
            fixedColumns:   {
                leftColumns: 2
            },
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'excel'
            ]
        });

        $('#MyButton').click(function(){
            table.scroller.toPosition( 50 );
        });

    } );

</script>
```

Comment: for the show also your using **$(column).hide();** you should have to use **$(column).show();**.

Comment: From the docs (https://datatables.net/reference/api/): get current row index by using `scroller.page()`, show / hide / toggle /whatever, set position (to original row index) with `scroller.toPosition()`

Comment: @ymz I added this line in ready function after initializing in "table" variable -  table.scroller.toPosition( 500 ); but it doesnt scrolled to anywhere after page loads.

Comment: `scroller.toPosition()` get a value that mach an existing index (from the docs https://datatables.net/reference/api/scroller.toPosition()).. Are you sure you have (at least) 500 items?

Comment: @ymz Yes i have tried it for many numbers 20, 50, 100 but it doesn't scroll at all.

Comment: `document.ready !== table.ready`.. please try to use `init.dt` listener and execute (only) the position code there (https://datatables.net/reference/api/state.loaded())

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this in your click:

```
$('#shipmentshortage').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#IdOfButtonYouClicked").offset().top
            }, 2000);//2000 would be height of your table
```